# Notepad++, windows command line, and unicode

Tags: python-3.x, shell, unicode

I've been playing around with unicode block elements and box drawing in python3.6, just printing to the command line to see what happens. I've found that only some of the characters will actually print. The full box (2588), halves (258C, 2590), certain lines (2550-256C) will print fine, but the quadrants(2596-2598, 259D), dashed lines (2504-250B), some of the corners, swaths of the intersections show as the boxed question mark. They appear as squared in notepad++ too.

Using the names (\N{QUADRANT LOWER LEFT}) doesn't work either.

According to Wikipedia all the characters should be in UTF-8, which is being used in notepad++, the command line, and Python 3. What's going on?

Comment: Run charmap.exe & check the font your using has those glyphs?

Comment: You're right, the ones I can't type aren't there. It's weird that some characters would be there and some wouldn't. Can I add them in? Or do I have to find a font with all the characters?

Comment: You really need a font with the characters. (or learn to use fontforge)